# How to download from GitHub without download zip button?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-for-windows

I can not download from GitHub because I can not find download zip button; it does not have for this link actually.

This is the link:

```
https://github.com/fholm/unityassets/tree/master/VoiceChat
```

Can you please help me with downloading free voice chat of unity?

Comment: download the whole project and take what you need.

Comment: how? how should I download whole project?

Comment: @ferfer folow the [link](https://github.com/fholm/unityassets) and press download zip, for example

Comment: Check the link to the question provided by @random - it answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each repo has an archive (zip image), in case you don't have Git to clone said repo.

In your case: https://github.com/fholm/unityassets/archive/master.zip

That will include the `VoiceChat` subfolder.

The other option is to clone the repo with Git of course.
In which case, [you could do a sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/6309) and clone only the subfolder of interest.